# Do $a^{1/n}$ and $n$th root of a mean the same thing?

Tags: notation, exponential-function

I encountered a question in which I had to find $x$ and the question had $3^{1/x}$ and I got $x=1/2$ and $1/4$ as its solution. But my textbook said that "$x$th root of $3$" is valid for $x\geq 2$ and $x$ should be a natural number.

But the question did not directly mention $x$th root 3 and instead "$3^{1/x}$". Do they actually mean the same? Do they have same restrictions on $x$?

PS: The actual question was "Solve for real values of $x$: log $4$ + ($1$+ $1/2x$) log $3$= log ($3^{1/x}$ + $27$)"

Comment: Can you quote what the entire question you were asked is? $3^{1/x}$ by itself is not a question.

Comment: It's be nice is you actually told us what the question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $b > 0; b\ne 1$ then $b^x; x \in \mathbb R$ has a rather complicated definition based on calculus which I won't actually go into detail what it is but it is all based on the fundamental relation $b^{x+y} = b^xb^y$.

But there are some basic concepts that fall into generalizations.

$b^0 = 1$ (it *has* to if $b^x = b^{0+x} = b^0b^x$)

And if $n\in \mathbb N$ then $b^n = \underbrace{b\cdot ..... \cdot b}$.

And if $x = \frac 1n; n\in \mathbb N$ then, yes, $b^{\frac 1n}$ will indeed have to be then $n$th root of $b$.  They are the same thing.

(It *has* to be..... If $b^{x+y} = b^xb^y$ then $(b^{\frac 1n})^n = \underbrace{b^{\frac 1n } \cdot ...\cdot b^{\frac 1n}} = b^{\frac 1n + \frac 1n + ....+\frac 1n} = b^1 = b$.)

So *IF* we assume $x$ is a natural number then $3^{\frac 1x}$ *will* be the $x$th root of $3$.

But you haven't actually told us what the *question* was or why we should assume $x$ is a natural number.

If $x$ is a real number we *do* have $(b^{\frac 1x})^x = b^{\frac xx} = b^1 = b$.  So whatever $b^{\frac 1x}$ is, if we raise it to the $x$ power we will get $b$.  We can casually refer to that as "the $x$th root of $b$" but if $x$ is not a natural number that might no be clear what that means. After all $3^{\frac 1{\pi}} = 3^{0.318....} \approx 1.4186....$ and $(3^{\frac 1{\pi}})^\pi =(1.4186.....)^{3.1415....} = 3$.  So we *could* so $3^{\frac 1\pi}$ is the $\pi$th root of $3$ but... that's not usually what we mean by "root".  Which usually means a root is a solution to a polynomial.  And as a polynomial only has *natural* numbers as powers as solution to $x^\pi = 3$ isn't usually called a "root".... at least, *I* wouldn't call it that.

But... FWIW..... The number $3^{\frac 1x}$ *will* always be a solution to "$w^x = 3$ solve for $w$".

Answer (score -1):

Well, in general they mean the same.
but it mostly depends on who is asking you the question, so they might have one of the following differences:

1. $\root 2 \of 4$ means both $-1$ and $1$ while $4^{\frac{1}{2}}$ means just the principle root, $2$.
2. it might hint that negative numbers are to be used as exponents as the expression $\root -1 \of {2} = \frac{1}{2}$ is practically never used.
3. alot less popular but some writers define $\root 0 \of n = \begin{cases}
   1,  & n>0 \\
   \text{undefined}, & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$
   The best option is to ask the professor or lecturer.

Comment: 1. Are you claiming that there is a difference between $\sqrt[2]{4}$ and $\sqrt 4$? Because $\sqrt 4$ is always positive. 2. If $\sqrt[0]{n}$ meant anything, it would mean $n^{1/0}$, which is obviously undefined for all $n$.

Comment: $\sqrt[2]{4} =2$ not $1$.  And I'd say using $\sqrt[2]{4}$ to mean $-2$ or $2$ is *very* rarely done.  Nearly *always* $\sqrt[2]4$ is only the positive root.

Comment: Oh, sorry for messing up that example. I did not mean to imply there is a diffrence between $\sqrt 4$ and $\root 2 \of 4$.